# Is there a way to delete meeting invitiations from the original email?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

When I delete an email containing a meeting invite without accepting, the meeting still shows up grayed out on my calendar.  This makes my calendar hard to read and the notifications for these meetings provide a constant source of distraction.

Ideally I would like meetings to not show up on my calendar unless I accept them.  It tried this with filters but found that meetings I created were also filtered out.

Is there a way to delete the email containing a meeting invite and have it automatically removed it from my calendar (I do not want to send a response).

Comment: I assume you already saw these and you need it to NOT show at all when you click to delete these but just in case I wanted to share the links for preventing them from being automatically added as tentative before you click on them... It sounds like you only have those added when you click to delete as the note section in these state but... http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/disable-ability-create-tentative-appointments/ and https://www.msoutlook.info/question/do-not-automatically-accept-meeting-as-tentative. . .

Comment: I'm not sure if you could set these then create a rule to delete as-needed without touching them and if that'd prevent them from being added if you can delete without selecting them... Something to test or consider perhaps if these articles don't tell you what you need. I think though rather than just deleting these, if you DECLINE then they shouldn't show up at all... I assume you know this but thought I'd mention too.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  The macros in the first link look promising.  I'll have to dig into them a bit deeper when I have some time.